# Substitute parent tokens in child macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I'm looking to replace some tokens within a called macro but can't seem to determine the right ordering of expansion and\or deferral. For example:

```
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define REPLACE(hello,y) EXPAND(y)
REPLACE(goodbye, hello world)
```

In my mind the `REPLACE` macro would call the `EXPAND` macro, making it functionally identical to:

```
#define REPLACE(hello,y) hello world
```

Allowing the `hello world` to be transformed into `goodbye world`.

My compiler (MSVC 2017) doesn't seem to be doing that, so I suspect that I'm in the wrong here. I've read up on expansion and deferral and have tried many different combinations of `DEFER()` and `EXPAND()`, but none seem to give the result I'm after.

Does anyone have any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use macros to create macros. The only way to solve that is to use two levels of preprocessing. Perhaps if you could expand your question to be about *why* you want to do this, what the *actual* problem you try to solve might be, then we could help you with that instead?

Comment: Yeah I know macros can't create other macros...that was a poor wording on my part. Slightly reworded now.
Posting the purpose for this system is pretty convoluted and would make the actual question unclear. I understand that context sometimes helps with questions, but I think the distilled version is all that's needed in this case.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. If you have a macro call like `REPLACE(goodbye, hello, world)` (note the commas) then it is fairly easy to replace hello with goodbye. Is this what you want?

Comment: You can't get there from here... macro expansions don't work the way you're assuming they do.  When `REPLACE(goodbye, hello world)` is invoked, the first step is to take parameters mentioned in the replacement list (the `y` in `EXPAND(y)`; it matters not that this is in parentheses), and replace them with the corresponding arguments (once expanded, which is a noop since neither `hello` nor `goodbye` are object like macros).  That results in `EXPAND(hello world)`.  Once all of this is done, the result is rescanned, at which point that `EXPAND` is recognized as an invocation, causing recursion.

Comment: ...there are ways of detecting patterns and performing replacements, but they involve different kinds of approaches.  It's impossible to recommend one if we don't know what actual problem you're trying to tackle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how macro parameters are handled, and for a reason. If the use of a macro parameter name in the arguments to a macro could be replaced, then it would be impossible to write safe macros: accidentally using the name of a macro parameter would cause chaos, and there is no reason why a macro caller needs to know what the names of the parameters are. Macro parameters are local to the macro expansion, similar to the way that function parameters are local to the body of the function.

Here's the actual substitution algorithm, from §6.10.3.1/1 [Argument Substitution] of the C standard:

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list… is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

Note that the arguments are macro replaced *before* being placed into the macro expansion. Once that is done, the parameter names in the replacement list are no longer relevant, and are not part of the replaced text.

Once the macro invocation has been replaced with its expansion, the resulting tokens are then scanned again (§6.10.3.4: "The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace."). However, since the macro invocation has been completely replaced prior to this rescan, the parameter tokens no longer appear.

So this particular solution to your problem is a dead-end. I recommend that you back up a step and focus on the problem you actually wish to solve.

Comment: In hindsight, the part about keeping macros safe makes sense. Thanks for your help!